# javascript framework for building single page apps

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I know this question has been asked many times but I'm looking for a really lightweight, easy to use framework

I've already tried nodejs and backbonejs and I didn't really like the style of those frameworks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend [Batman.js](http://batmanjs.org/)

> **batman.js is a framework for building rich single-page browser applications.** It is written in Coffee Script and its API is developed with Coffee Script in mind, but of course you can use plain old JavaScript too.
>
> It’s got:
>
> **a stateful MVC architecture** a powerful binding system routable
>   controller actions pure HTML views toolchain support built on node.js
>   and cake The APIs are heavily inspired by Rails and designed to make
>   Rails devs feel right at home.